# Juce library plugin for phonegap

Tags: phonegap-plugins, juce

Is there any plugin available for `Juce` library which i can add and which can work for both IOS and android ? If not, how do i integrate `Juce` library in my Phone gap app ?

Answer (score 1):

There is no plug in. But you can use intro juicer for creating different projects. Xcode, Visual studio or Android.

Comment: I would be helpful if you provide me with certain links or demo examples.

Comment: Please download the JUCE framework http://www.juce.com/download
This framework has all the bits and component required for your project. 
Specifically look for IntroJuicer

Comment: Now days, it's referred to as ProJucer. https://juce.com/discover/projucer